# Table cells are not placed side by side in a PDF made with PHP and TCPDF

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

How can we get the below custom fields to show up in a Horizontal table in PDF where cells are placed side by side, not under each other? We are using TCPDF library https://tcpdf.org

We are expecting

```
header | header | header | header  //We want all headers to be on one row
Value  | Value  | Value  | Value   //We want all Values to be on one row
```

cell tables are not placed side by side using the below code

```
// Initialize the table
$tableHTML = '<table>';

foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
    $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
    if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }

    $tableHTML .= '<tr style="display: table-cell"th:each="col : ${col}"  >';
    $tableHTML .= '<th style= "border: 1px solid #999; font-weight:bold; color: #fff; background-color:#242c39;">' . $field['name'] . '</th>';
    $tableHTML .= '</tr>';
    $tableHTML .= '<tr style="display: table-cell"th:each="col : ${col}">';
    $tableHTML .= '<td style= "border: 1px solid #999;">' . $value . '</td>';
    $tableHTML .= '</tr>';
    
    
    
   
   
}

// Close the table
$tableHTML .= '</table>';

// Add the table to $organization_info
$organization_info2 .= $tableHTML;
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

When we changed the code to the follwing the table became a vertical table

```
$tableHTML = '<table>';
$fieldNames = [];
$fieldValues = [];
foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
    $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
    if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }

    $fieldNames[] = $field['name'];
    $fieldValues[] = $value;
}

foreach ($fieldNames as $index => $fieldName) {
    $fieldValue = $fieldValues[$index];
    $tableHTML .= '<tr>';
    $tableHTML .= '<th style="border: 1px solid #999; font-weight:bold; color: #fff; background-color:#242c39;">' . $fieldName . '</th>';
    
    $tableHTML .= '<td style="border: 1px solid #999;">' . $fieldValue . '</td>';
    $tableHTML .= '</tr>';
}

$tableHTML .= '</table>';
```

Please check this:

[image]

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you want... your question should state the exact output you're expecting.  Please can you [edit] your question to show whether you're expecting `header | value | header | value` on a single row... or two rows where the first is `header | header` and the second is `value | value`

Comment: We are expecting 
```
header | header | header | header  //We want all headers to be on one row
Value  | Value  | Value  | Value   //We want all Values to be on one row
```

Comment: OK, then you need to code it like the pseudo code in my answer... build the cells in two separate variables, and then combine it all into the table structure

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new row for each header and a new row for each value... that's why they don't sit side-by-side.

Instead you need to build the header and value cells individually, and combine them together to create a single row for each.

This is a pseudo example...

```
$headers = "";
$values = "";
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $header .= "<th>" . $field['name'] . "</th>";
   $values .= "<td>" . $field['value'] . "</td>";
}
$table = "<table>";
$table .= "<thead><tr>" + $headers + "</tr></thead>";
$table .= "<tbody><tr>" + $values + "</tr></tbody>";
$table .= "</table>";
```

The result will be that your individual header cells will be together, and your value cells will be together

---

Although the question is about PHP, here is an equivalent javascript version to prove the concept achieves the result you desire...

```js
let data = [{"name": "One", "value": 1},{"name": "Two", "value": 2}];
let headers = "";
let values = "";
data.forEach(function(field) {
  headers += "<th>" + field.name + "</th>";
  values += "<td>" + field.value + "</td>";
});
let html = "<table border='1'>";
html += "<thead><tr>" + headers + "</tr></thead>";
html += "<tbody><tr>" + values + "</tr></tbody>";
html += "</table>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to create variables, then you can build it like this instead...

```
$table = "<table>";
$table = "<thead><tr>";
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $table .= "<th>" . $field['name'] . "</th>";
}
$table = "</tr><thead>";
$table = "<tbody><tr>";
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $table.= "<td>" . $field['value'] . "</td>";
}
$table = "</tr><tbody>";
$table .= "</table>";
```

And another javascript example...

```js
let data = [{"name": "One", "value": 1},{"name": "Two", "value": 2}];
let html = "<table border='1'>";
html += "<thead><tr>";
data.forEach(function(field) {
  html += "<th>" + field.name + "</th>";
});
html += "</tr></thead>";
html += "<tbody><tr>";
data.forEach(function(field) {
  html += "<td>" + field.value + "</td>";
});
html += "</tr></tbody>";
html += "</table>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: add a condition: $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
 if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }

Comment: It gave us a fetal w\error when we tried to use your code

Comment: The code is not making the table side by side it cause the value to disappear $tableHTML = '<table>';

foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
    $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
    if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }
    

    $tableHTML .= "<tr>";
    $tableHTML .= "<th>" . $field['name'] . "</th>";
    $tableHTML .= "<td>" . $field['value'] . "</td>";
    $tableHTML .= "</tr>";
    
    
    
   
   
}

// Close the table
$tableHTML .= '</table>';
$organization_info2 .= $tableHTML;

Comment: @WonderInWonderland - I have reverted my answer to my original one, as your question was not clear.  My code is not plug-and-play... it's pseudo.  It is there to give you the idea of how you can achieve the result, but you need to code it yourself (you'll learn more than copy/paste)

Comment: We are expecting 
```
header | header | header | header  //We want all headers to be on one row
Value  | Value  | Value  | Value   //We want all Values to be on one row
```
Your code is just making it: 
header | value   //on one row
header | value  //on one row
header | value  //on one row
header | value  //on one row
header | value //on one row
We edit the main question to make it very clear.

Comment: I'm sorry @Wonder, but my pseudo code will do exactly what you want.  If you're getting `header|value|header|value` then you have coded it incorrectly and not following my example. I'm not writing your code for you... you will learn a lot more by taking my example and modifying your code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you need/mean a horizontal line of data, then do not repeat the `<tr>` tag, instead repeat only the `th` and `td`

```
$tableHTML = '<table>';
$tableHTML .= '<tr>';

foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
    ...
    $tableHTML .= '<th>' . $field['name'] . '</th>';
    $tableHTML .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
$tableHTML .= '</tr>';
$tableHTML .= '</table>';
```